# NosuchElement error while hovering highchart tooltip using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, highcharts

I am trying to use https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/selenium/graphs/LineChart.java code to test tooltip values for highchart graph. But I am getting the error:

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"css selector","selector":"g.highcharts-series-group >
>   g:nth-child(1)"}"

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseUrl = "http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic";

// launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
driver.get(baseUrl);
WebElement highChartSVGElement = driver.findElement(By.className("highcharts-container"));
LineChart chartObject = new LineChart(driver, highChartSVGElement);
if(chartObject.isChartDisplayed() && chartObject.isTooltipDisplayed()) {
    chartObject.hoverOverPointOfGraphAtXAxisLabel("Jan");
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code of the chart. Selenium webdriver is throwing NosuchElementException because it cannot find any element based on the given locator.so post te html code here for reference

Comment: You should implement WebDriverWait here to find an element...

Comment: I get below error for WebDriverWait : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for visibility of Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.cssSelector: g.highcharts-series-group > g:nth-child(1)'